# Mocha tests – finish "before" completely, then running "it"s

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm running some tests using Mocha `6.1.4` (under WebdriverIO `5.11.6`). I want to *complete the execution of something* in `before` (read: store some values via an HTTP call) and then start running the tests – the `it` fellows. Basically, do everythig as if it were synchronous calls. This is (an excerpt of) the (TypeScript) code that I'm using:

```
// file: ./test/service.spec.ts

describe("#this stuff", () => {
  before(() => {
    browser.url("login-url");
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    const service: TheService = new TheService();
    return service.setUp(); // ...superagent returns a Promise
  });

  it("should-do-it", () => {
      // ...test + expectations here
    });
  });
});
```

---

```
// ./src/the-service.ts

import * as superagent from "superagent";

// ...

public setUp() {
  return superagent.post(this.uri)
      .accept("application/json")
      .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .send(body)
      .then();
}
```

If I understood correctly the Mocha [docs](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) (and some questions/answers also here in StackOverflow), returning a `Promise` inside `beforeEach` it is all I need to accomplish this, but so far, it doesn't work.

The only consistent way I've found is to execute the content of the `it` method as a `setUp()`'s callback:

```
// ...inside `it`
service.setUp().then(() => {
  // ...test + expectations here
});
```

Can somebody versed on the ECMAScript / TypeScript world shed some light here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  const service: TheService = new TheService();
  await service.setUp(); // ...superagent returns a Promise
});
```

Comment: ...yeah, I already tried that too; forgot to put it in the question O:)